# Cannot Send Acknowledgement to GPS device FM1125 using Nodejs net module

Tags: node.js

i'm trying to capture the data form GPS device Teltonika FM1125. 
This device first sends IMEI number and on Acknowledgement it sends the coordinates data.
i'm receiving the IMEI number but when i try to send acknowledgment its still sending the same old data.

i'm using nodejs net module to create server.Here's what i tried.

```
const server = net.createServer((c) => {
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('data', (data) => {
     console.log(data);
     var textChunk = data.toString();
     if(textChunk.length<20){
            c.write("01", function () {
              console.log('response send to device');
            });
     }
    console.log(textChunk);    
  });

  c.on('end', () => {
      console.log('client disconnected');
  })
});

server.on('error', (err) => {
  throw err;
});

server.listen(9030, () => {
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are writing the string "01" to the socket, when writing to the socket this string will be encoded as a UTF-8 string. You can pass an argument to the .write() method to override this encoding. This will not write the byte 0x01 to the socket, instead it will write the bytes 0x30 0x31. These 2 bytes represent the string "01".

You would probably be better off passing a UInt8Array to the .write() method, containing one byte with the value 0x01.

Comment: How to do that in code?